# I got a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token error on void loop() { when I compile it for my arduino

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-ide

When I try to compile this in Arduino IDE it gives me the error "a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
" on the `void loop() {` line

```
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.
 
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  Serial.println();

}
void loop() {

  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "xxxxxxxx") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized access");
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
  }
 
 else   {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this your complete sketch? you try to instance an MFRC522 object without including the library on the top. Other than that, I don't see any of code will cause the compilation error you described.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it working, it was a corrupted version of IDE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).